# Adding day names to getDate() function

Tags: javascript, json, api, date, project

So I have this project that I'm working on. I'm trying to add names of the dates on this code that returns present weeks dates (Mon, Tue, Wed etc.).

This is what my code currently looks like:

```
            // Get the current date
            var curr = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);

            // First day
            var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay();

            // Last day
            var last = first + 6; 

            var startDate = new Date(curr.setDate(first));
            var endDate = new Date(curr.setDate(last));
```

I would like to add, that I'm using this this part of the code for a project, where we print school timetables from our schools own API. I'm using this code to fetch the current weeks timetables with a JSON query:

```
var getData = {
                "startDate": startDate,
                "endDate": endDate,
                "studentGroup": [
                 ""
                ]
            };
```

I can provide more information about the project if needed.

I would really appreciate your help here. Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

In order for the JSON query to work, startDate and endDate need to be in this form (eg. below);

```
YYYY-MM-DD'T'H:mm   eg. 2020-12-31T12:50
```

Comment: What are you expecting of *`var curr = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);`* ??

Comment: ...and you didn't show what you have tried to solve your *actual problem*

Comment: I haven't tried anything specific yet.

And when it comes to `var curr = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);`

That snip of code gives the current weeks dates. From monday to sunday, if thats what you asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at your code I managed to came up with an solution.

First you need to make a list for the day names

```
var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
```

Then you need to go through your `responseText` after `JSON.parse()` and make an array for the object:

```
var json = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
var dataList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < json.reservations.length; i++) {
    if (json.reservations[i].resources != null) {
        for (var j = 0; j < json.reservations[i].resources.length; j++) {    
            var reservation = json.reservations[i];
            var resource = json.reservations[i].resources[j];
```

After this you can get the name of the days and add them to your array with this:

```
// Name of the day
var day = new Date(reservation.startDate);                          
dataList.push(days[day.getDay()]);
```

Comment: Yes. I sent you that one sir.

Answer (score 2):

Since `getDay()` gives you the integer value of the `Day`. You can use an Array to get the Days,eg,

```
var Days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat']
```

Therefore you can easily get the Day by

```
var currDay = Days[new Date().getDay()]
```

Comment: @Destiny_Coder_88 please upvote and mark as answer if you are satisfied by the solution

Answer (score 1):

You can also use like this one

```
var date = new Date();   // return timestamp object
date = date.toString();  // return timestamp  as string
date = date.substring(0,3); // return the day name
alert(date);
```

Thanks,

Comment: The value returned by *Date.prototype.toString* is implementation dependent and may not contain the day name at all, much less in a particular position in the string.